# Setting up a sever on Google Cloud with Postgresql database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying for about two weeks now to set up a server for a completed Django app on the google cloud shell. All of the documentation for gcloud is confusing and sends me to several different pages for one task and it is very hard to keep track of what to do. Sites like digitalocean, which is useful for Django program setup, doesn't work on gcloud. I haven't figured out a way to connect a postgres VM to my program through the cloud shell despite having the server running. I am very lost in setting this up. Could someone please help me set up my Django app? It runs perfectly on localhost but when trying to implement it into the google cloud nothing works.

I've done the django-gcloud tutorial already and set up a simple site just by importing the code from google, which doesn't help because all it does is import a completed app and you just type in "gcloud app deploy" which doesn't explain how to set it up so that you can do that.

My program uses python 3, DjangoRestFramework, and Celery. The database is Postgresql.

My full module list is:

```
Django-1.11.2 amqp-2.1.4 astroid-1.5.3 billiard-3.5.0.2 celery-4.0.2 djangorestframework-3.6.3 isort-4.2.15 kombu-4.0.2 lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1 mccabe-0.6.1 pep8-1.7.0 psycopg2-2.7.1 pylint-1.7.2 pytz-2017.2 six-1.10.0 vine-1.1.3 wrapt-1.10.10
```

Comment: It might make more sense to use Cloud SQl, which currently supports PostgreSQL in beta

Comment: @holdenweb I'll look into this thanks